# Fetch json data using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a json file and I want to display it data using PHP. My below code gives me error,

```
$json = file_get_contents('data.json'); 
$data = json_decode($json,true);
$users = $data['devices'];
foreach($users as $user)
{
echo $user['id'];
echo $user['user'];
}
```

When I replace the 3rd LOC with `$users = $data['user'];` then it display some data with single alphabet i don't know in which order.

**Data.json** file contains the following data

```
{
"user":
    {
    "id":"#03B7F72C1A522631",
    "user":"test@mail.com",
    "password":"123",
    "email":"test@mail.com",
    "name":"m",
    "creationDate":1385048478,
    "compression":true,
    "imageProfile":"medium",
    "videoProfile":"medium",
    "blockAdvert":true,
    "blockTracking":true,
    "devices":[
        {
        "id":"#13C73379A7CC2310",
        "udid":"cGMtd2luNi4xLV",
        "user":"test@mail.com",
        "creationDate":1385048478,
        "status":"active",
        }, 
        {
        "id":"#FE729556EDD9910D",
        "udid":"C1N1",
        "user":"test@mail.com",
        "creationDate":1385291938,
        "status":"active",
        }]
    },
"status":
    {
    "version":"0.9.5.0",
    "command":"getuser",
    "opf":"json",
    "error":false,
    "code":0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may want do display all the `devices` info, you can change you code to:

```
$json = file_get_contents('data.json'); 
$data = json_decode($json,true);

// change the variable name to devices which is clearer.
$devices = $data['user']['devices'];
foreach ($devices as $device)
{
    echo $device['id'];
    echo $device['user'];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe you skipped 1 node, try:

```
$users = $data['user']['devices'];
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work;

```
$json = file_get_contents('data.json'); 
$data = json_decode($json,true);
$users = $data['user']['devices'];
foreach($users as $user) {
    echo $user['id'];
    echo $user['user'];
}
```

There is one key *before* 'devices'.

Answer (score 1):

You are not accessing your json correctly.  You need to access it like this.

```
$yourVariable = $data['users']['devices'];
```

Try that.

Comment: OP wrote `$data = json_decode($json,true);` which returns an array instead of object.

Comment: http://docs.php.net/json_decode the documentation says that if the parameter $assoc is true it will turn objects into associative arrays.  I am pretty sure this is false by default correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: http://www.phpriot.com/manual/php/function.json-decode this example shows an object is returned by default if the $assoc parameter is left out.

Comment: It defaults to false, but OP explicit wrote true